# Raphael JS Dynamic path update not working in IE 11

Tags: raphael, internet-explorer-11

When I try to have a path follow the mouse pointer in IE 11 it wont work, but it works fine in Chrome.

Please see the code here http://jsfiddle.net/3xy3oba2/1/

```
    <body>
            <div id="container" onmousemove="move(event)"></div>
            <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>

            <script>

                    var paper = Raphael("container", 500, 500);

                    console.log("Path redraw test");

                    var arrow = paper.path("M 250, 250, L 0, 0");
                    arrow.attr('stroke-width', 2);
                    arrow.attr('stroke', "#0000FF");
                    arrow.attr('arrow-end', "classic-wide-long");

                    function move(event)
                    {
                            var x = event.layerX;
                            var y = event.layerY;

                            var path = "M 250, 250, L " + x + ", " + y;                    

                            arrow.attr('path', path);
                    }

            </script>


    </body>
```

Anyone got a idea about what goes wrong?

Comment: Seems to be a bug related to arrow-end. If you comment it out, it will work.

Comment: Thank you, I think I can find an acceptable work around using that. Also I guess I need to file a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around mentioned above is this. Remove the arrow head, change the path, add the arrow head back.

Update code here: http://jsfiddle.net/7fz5qb7e/2/

Also found the same solution here, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/raphaeljs/m-H63bb7Nsw

Full JS code here:

```
    <body>
            <div id="container" onmousemove="move(event)"></div>
            <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>

            <script>

                    var paper = Raphael("container", 500, 500);

                    console.log("Path redraw test");

                    var arrow = paper.path("M 250, 250, L 0, 0");
                    arrow.attr('stroke-width', 2);
                    arrow.attr('stroke', "#0000FF");
                    arrow.attr('arrow-end', "classic-wide-long");

                    function move(event)
                    {
                            var x = event.offsetX;
                            var y = event.offsetY;

                            var path = "M 250, 250, L " + x + ", " + y;                    
                            arrow.attr('arrow-end', "");
                            arrow.attr("path", path);
                            arrow.attr('arrow-end', "classic-wide-long");
                    }

            </script>


    </body>
```